# How to modify an XML attribute with XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I wonder if there's a way in XSLT to modify / add to an attribute value.

Right now I am simply replacing the attribute value:

```
<a class="project" href="#">
  <xsl:if test="new = 'Yes'">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">project new</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if>
</a>
```

But I don't like the repetition of `project` in line 2. Is there a better way to do this, e.g. to simply *add* `new` at the end of the attribute?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the `if` inside the `attribute` instead of the other way round:

```
<a href="#">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:text>project</xsl:text>
    <xsl:if test="new = 'Yes'">
      <xsl:text> new</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

An `<xsl:attribute>` can contain any valid XSLT template (including `for-each` loops, applying other templates, etc.), the only restriction being that instantiating this template must only generate *text nodes*, not elements, attributes, etc.  The attribute value will be the concatenation of all these text nodes.

Comment: Thanks. This solution is actually quite simple, so it's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks and Happy New Year!

Answer (score 0):

**In XSLT 1.0 one can use this one-liner**:

```
<a class="project{substring(' new', 5 - 4*(new = 'Yes'))}"/>
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <a class="project{substring(' new', 5 - 4*(new = 'Yes'))}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>
 <new>Yes</new>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a class="project new"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Templates)
2. To select a string based on condition, in XPath 1.0 one can use the substring function and specify as the starting-index argument an expression, which evaluates to 1 when the condition is `true()` and to some number that is greater than the length of the string -- otherwize.
3. We use the fact that in XPath 1.0 any argument of the `*` (multiplication) operator is converted to a number, and that `number(true()) = 1` and `number(false()) = 0`

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

**Use this one-liner**:

```
  <a class="project{(' new', '')[current()/new = 'Yes']}"/>
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <a class="project{(' new', '')[current()/new = 'Yes']}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the same XML document (above), again the same wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<a class="project new"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Proper use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)**.
2. Proper use of **[sequences](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel/#sequences)**.
3. Proper use of XSLT the **[`current()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current)** function.

Comment: Thanks so much. I went with Ian's solution this time because I am still quite new to XSLT but I will probably get back to your idea later. Have a good one!